# unable to add jitpack components in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jitpack

I am unable to add jitpack components in android studio

I have added these lines to my repositories

```
maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

but still unable to add any jitpack repository like this

```
 compile 'com.github.HendrixString:Android-Zorn:e6d81f7a62'
```

I am using android studio 1.4

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: Disable offline mode and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

You Must Add it to Repository in app/build.gradle

```
repositories{
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and include your library in to dependencies

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.github.HendrixString:Android-Zorn:e6d81f7a62'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That project doesn't build because it's build file is incomplete. It missing this bit:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

The log:
 https://jitpack.io/com/github/HendrixString/Android-Zorn/e6d81f7a62/build.log